# Page attribute template dropdown not displayed even the syntax is correct

Tags: theme-development, page-template

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: foo
*/
?>
```

I added this to my foo.php but dropdown not displayed in admin panel.

Comment: Yes this working fine. However create templete file in your theme root directory. Goto your page post type... It should be work.

Comment: @Faysal Mahumud Not working in my case i am using wordpress 4.7.3

Comment: which theme you use?? set twenty seventeen from theme appearance and check.

Comment: I am using my custom theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to enable the Page Template dropdown for a custom post type, you have to enable support for "page attributes" when you define your CPT.

You should currently have something like

```
register_post_type('foo',
    array('labels' => array(
        ...
    ),
);
```

You need to add 'supports':

```
register_post_type('foo',
    array('labels' => array(
        ...
    ),
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'page-attributes'),
);
```

'page-attributes' will allow your CPT to use Page Templates, which is what enables the dropdown menu. 'title', 'editor', etc. etc. are optional depending on your needs.

Since your CPT is already defined, you will probably need to first call `unregister_post_type()` to "unregister" it and then re-register it with your new code.