# How to use custom template files in deeper directory?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

On an install to which I've just returned (and forgotten much of what I'd done), I'd had my custom templates in folders a level deeper than 'page-templates', using a function (example below)to enable them.

```
add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', function( $templates ) {
// Contact.
$templates['page-templates/contact/email.php'] = 'Contact: email';
return $templates;});
```

I now notice that this works ok on pages but not CPTs - and am wondering whether they can work with CPTs, and if so, how.

(A plugin enables template selection for CPTs, but templates deeper than the 'page-templates' directory aren't available for selection. And this behavior is the same when using the recently-introduced WP feature to enable additional templates for CPTs. To be clear, it seems that custom templates for pages can be deeper than root+1 but templates for CPTs can't.)

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of CPTs directory structure?

Comment: When you created the CPT did you enable 'page-attributes'? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/263966/page-attribute-template-dropdown-not-displayed-even-the-syntax-is-correct/263999#263999

Comment: @Vinod Dalvi ... the structure is as noted above: a 'page-templates' directory contains various subdirectories which contain other directories containing template files... example: 'contact', 'channel' (where 'contact' is a page, and 'channel' is a CPT). For pages, the templates in deeper directories are recognised and used (example: page-templates/contact/email.php), but for CPTs the templates in deeper directories are unavailable in the attributes dropdown menu.

Comment: @WebElaine... yes, 'page attributes' are enabled - the dropdowns are present, but don't show templates at deeper levels (if i move them up a level, into 'page templates' they become available.

Comment: You said "A plugin enables template selection for CPTs". Which plugin? If you share your whole solution then i can test it on my test site and troubleshoot it.

Comment: @Vinod Dalvi... Thanks. The plugin (Template for Custom Post Types) is no longer needed, now that WP core enables CPT templates. And I don't think there's anything to test, because there's nothing wrong - it appears that WP treats CPTs this way.